# Database design - Optional fields

Tags: database-design, field, option-type

I'm about to add a field which gives users an optional title. Is it good practise to create an extra table with 1 or more fields with an id to serve as a lookup? Is this considered efficient and are there other solutions?

Comment: Is the optional field a free text field or more a dropdown kinda field?

Comment: It's a simple string value with a custom title that appears under the username.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to offer people a choice from a list of titles, and intend to do analysis on this field, then it would be worthwhile to normalize it. Otherwise, the minor savings in space would be unlikely to outweigh the inconvenience.

Empty fields don't take up any space in a database unless they are fixed width (and maybe not even then, depending on the DMBS). The benefit is not in avoiding empty fields, it would be in avoiding repeated or dirty data, which makes decent analysis impossible.

Comment: The list of titles is set. For example, it could include "user","moderator,"administrator","contributor", etc. I suppose the proper way to do this would be to have an id column in the main table and a second table as a lookup so titles can be modified without having to process the main table.

Comment: Then it should be a reference table like you say. If they are choosing from a list, it should always be a reference table, otherwise you risk bad data, and since you're already using a related table to get your list of options, it's not any more work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For Searching purpose it is best to have extra table, but for only optional title you can create another field in same table.

Comment: Thanks ime. How many fields do you feel would justify an extra table?

Comment: two field one for id and other for title. i think, and if you want in other situation where defined field so do that.